# Error using Drush on Windows 7 using Cgwin & Composer for Installation - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: drush

I am using Windows 7 64, with WAMPServer64, with Cygwin and composer installed.

- C:\cygwin64
- C:\wamp
- C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\Composer

I have followed all the steps required to complete a successful install of Drush. Everything seems to work correctly as far as I can tell. Here's the output of a `drupal status` command.

```
Drupal version                  :  7.32
 Site URI                        :  http://default
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database hostname               :  localhost
 Database port                   :
 Database username               :  db
 Database name                   :  db
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
 Drupal user                     :
 Default theme                   :  theme548
 Administration theme            :  garland
 PHP executable                  :  /cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php
 PHP configuration               :  C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
 PHP OS                          :  WINNT
 Drush script                    :  C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\d
                                    rush.php
 Drush version                   :  7.1.0
 Drush temp directory            :  C:\cygwin64\tmp
 Drush configuration             :
 Drush alias files               :
 Install profile                 :  standard
 Drupal root                     :  C:\wamp\www\projects\dev\Mirror
 Site path                       :  sites/default
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files
 Private file directory path     :  sites/default/files/private
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
```

However, when I execute the following command, I receive an error.

```
Initialized Drupal 7.32 root directory at                   [notice]
C:\wamp\www\projects\dev\Mirror
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default            [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file="C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\dru2DAB.tmp" --database=db --host=localhost --silent  < "C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\dru2DAA.tmp"
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file="C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\dru2E29.tmp" --database=db --host=localhost --silent  < "C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\dru2E28.tmp"
Loading release_info engine.                                [notice]
Loading version_control engine.                             [notice]
Loading package_handler engine.                             [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Loading update_status engine.                               [notice]
/cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php                      [notice]
"C:\\Users\\dev\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\drush\\drush\\drush.php"
--php=/cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php  --backend=2
--verbose
--root="C:\\wamp\\www\\projects\\dev\\Mirror"
--uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus drupal 2>&1
Illegal string offset 'site' backend.inc:1030            [warning]
The command could not be executed successfully (returned:[error]
The system cannot find the path specified.
, code: 1)
pm-updatestatus failed.                                  [error]
Command dispatch complete                                   [notice]
Command dispatch complete                                   [notice]
```

The specific error being returned:

```
Illegal string offset 'site' backend.inc:1030            [warning]
The command could not be executed successfully (returned:[error]
The system cannot find the path specified.
, code: 1)
```

I cannot seem to track down this issue and I do not know enough about Drush to fix this error.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

Comment: I also would like to mention that from within the site directory, drush cc all (Clearing all the Drupal site cache) works correctly.

Comment: Along with the clearing of cache command, `drush pm-updatestatus` command works correctly as well.